# getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection warning on android

Tags: java, android, logcat

I get the following warning in my logcat.

```
getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

I'm unable to find the reason behind it. Please help

Comment: I don't understand what's ambiguous/vague/incomplete in this question ? I get this warning in my logcat while running my app, I want to know the reason for this warning.

Comment: I'm also seing this in my application that I'm developing and I have no idea where it comes from or why. If anyone ever finds out, please post a comment. It actually shows many different warnings other then "getExtractedText". I also see: "beginBatchEdit", "endBatchEdit", "getTextBeforeCursor" and many more.

Comment: are the moderators having a look at this question. If not then they should because if they still believe this question as vague and amibiguous even after 14 upvotes then I don't know what to say

Comment: I concur, this is a problem I also need to address. I have no idea of the cause.

Comment: @frieza add a more detailed LogCat output and (if you can) some background information and we'll see if it can be reopened.

Comment: What code do you have that's causing this error?

Comment: Are you getting this warning when you enter text to EditText using a soft keyboard?

Comment: @BilltheLizard it is pretty normal code, I get this error when running the code on my device (samsung galaxy s), but no such warning when running the code on the emulator, so I'm really not sure which block of code could cause this warning to pop-up

Comment: @Krishnabhadra no, this warning shows up randomly even if I'm not using edittext

Comment: In my app, this appears when closing it. No idea why.

Comment: For me this is related to the Swype keyboard, any time I click on (or out of) a text field it gives that warning (along with several others, as have been mentioned). @Emile's answer below seems to make sense, in that something is failing with the input method.

Comment: This can be reproduced with the login dialog example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout  Select a text field in the dialog and then change screen orientation

Answer (score 49):

I ran into a similar issue. My logcat:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21214): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21214): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21214): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21214): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
...
I/Choreographer(20010): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

My situation:
I have an EditText view the user types into. The EditText gets cleared when user presses a button. Lots of inactive InputConnection entries stream out when I rapidly press the button.

Ex:

```
editText.setText(null);
```

The last line in my logcat above provides a great indication of what is happening. Sure enough, the InputConnection is overwhelmed by requests to clear the text. I tried modifying the code to check for text length before trying to clear it:

```
if (editText.length() > 0) {
    editText.setText(null);
}
```

This helps mitigate the problem in that pressing the button rapidly no longer causes the stream of IInputConnectionWrapper warnings. However this is still prone to problems when the user rapidly alternates between typing something and pressing the button or presses the button when the app is under sufficient load, etc.

Fortunately, I found another way to clear text: [Editable.clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#clear()). With this I don't get warnings at all:

```
if (editText.length() > 0) {
    editText.getText().clear();
}
```

Note that should you wish to clear all input state and not just the text (autotext, autocap, multitap, undo), you can use [TextKeyListener.clear(Editable e)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TextKeyListener.html#clear%28android.text.Editable%29).

```
if (editText.length() > 0) {
    TextKeyListener.clear(editText.getText());
}
```

Comment: I was getting IInputConnectionWrapper warnings also and my app got almost ANR, method clear() worked for me...super strange bug, before i was setting setText("");

Answer (score 22):

**Update:**

The reason I was getting InputConnection warnings was not because of where I was setting the text (i.e, in the `onTextChanged` callback, or the `afterTextChanged`) -- it was because I was using `setText`.

I got around the issue by calling:

```
hiddenKeyboardText.getText().clear();
hiddenKeyboardText.append("some string");
```

Note: I still make the call in the `afterTextChanged` callback, though it works without warnings from `ontextChanged` as well.

**Previous answer:**

I was getting identical messages in logcat as well, though my scenario was slightly different. I wanted to read every character that came into EditText (or composed characters/pasted text), and then reset the EditText in question to a default initialisation string.

The clear text part works as per Johnson's solution above. However, resetting the text was problematic, and I'd get inputconnection warnings.

Initially, my `onTextChanged(CharSequence s, ...)` was defined as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (isResettingKeyboard)
        return;

    // ... do what needs to be done

    resetKeyboardString();

}

public void resetKeyboardString()
{
    isResettingKeyboard = true;

    hiddenKeyboardText.getText().clear();
    hiddenKeyboardText.setText(keyboardInitString);
    hiddenKeyboardText.setSelection(defaultKeyboardCursorLocation);

    isResettingKeyboard = false;
}
```

When `onTextChanged(...)` is called, the EditText is in readonly mode. I am not sure if this means we can't do more than call `getText.clear()` on it (`setText(...)` calls produce inputConnection warnings as well).

However, the callback `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` is the right place to set the text.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (isResettingKeyboard)
        return;

    resetKeyboardString();

    // ... 
}
```

This is, thus far, working without any warnings.

Comment: I had the same problem too. What I realized was that though your solution makes disappear the InputConnection warnings, I noticed that  `afterTextChanged` method is called on `hiddenKeyboardText.getText().clear();` as well as on `hiddenKeyboardText.append("some string");`, and this fact should also be taken into account. +1 from me!

Comment: @Nick true -- important to ensure `if (isResettingKeyboard) return;` is on top...

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem. The warning appeared when the soft keyboard was activated in one of my `EditTexts` and the activity lose focus.

What I did was to hide the keyboard in onPause();

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    // hide the keyboard in order to avoid getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: This is the answer all right. Make sure you hide the keyboard before you switch away from the activity you currently have on screen.

Answer (score 7):

From the help documents

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html

> The InputConnection interface is the communication channel from an
>   InputMethod back to the application that is receiving its input. It is
>   used to perform such things as reading text around the cursor,
>   committing text to the text box, and sending raw key events to the
>   application.

In addition, further reading shows

> getExtractedText():
>   This method may fail either if the input connection has become invalid
>   **(such as its process crashing) or the client is taking too long to
>   respond with the text (it is given a couple seconds to return)**. In
>   either case, a null is returned.

It appears to also monitor changes to such text, and alert changes.

To hunt the issue down you'll have to explore any database queries you are making, perhaps around listViews or lists in a layout.

If you don't have any views, for example it's happening randomly in the background, then i would suggest that its not a UI element issue, so ignore textfields and such. It could be a background service that's storing information in a cursor or requesting a cursor.

Also, does the issue arise from your app? or perhaps someone else's that you've installed recently. List the full logCat trace. Someone might recognise the issue.

I would hazard a guess that if you haven't written something specific around this that its someone elses log message, or perhaps that of a library your using?

Comment: thanks, I do make db queries but strangely this warning doesn't show up when running the app on emulator, so it might actually be due to some other app installed on my device. Will look into this direction

Comment: I think the latest logCat shows you your messages distinct from other apps, filtered. Haven't used it sufficiently enough to confirm that though. You could create a new empty app, and watch the log cat to see if the error occurs, that would eliminate your app. from being the issue.

Comment: @frieza not necessarily other app. I have added ArrayAdapter with sqlite and am now getting this warning on phone as well. I guess you see no errors on emulator is because it is being slow and performance thresholds are being disabled as a consequence.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from antoniom's answer, make sure that any further actions needed to be done, are really done after hiding the keyboard, so if you have hidden the keyboard like the one below:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

, you need to have succeeding actions performed post the keyboard hiding, like so:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish(); //Sample succeeding code
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue for myself maybe you have the same problem.

This was caused by an **Object** in the **HeaderView** of the **List Adapter**.

I inflated a **View** and declared the **Object** and put a **TextWatcher** on it.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(CONTEXT).inflate(R.layout.in_overscrollview, null);
Object= (Object) v.findViewById(R.id.OBJECT_ID);

Object.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Do my work
        //Update my view
        }
});
```

Added it to the **List Adapter** and built the adapter.

```
JobListView = (ListView) getListView().findViewWithTag("JOBLISTVIEWTAG");
JobListView.addHeaderView(v, null, false);
JobsAdapter = new IN_JOBS_ADAPTER(CONTEXT, ITEMS_FOR_ADATER);
ListView.setAdapter(JOBSadapter);
```

Everything is fine the **Text Watcher** works.

**BUT** if I ever rebuilt the adapter after the initial build.

```
JobsAdapter = new IN_JOBS_ADAPTER(CONTEXT, DIFFERENT_ITEMS_FOR_ADAPTER);
ListView.setAdapter(JOBSadapter);
```

That **HeaderView** is rebuilt too.

That warning would show because the **Object** was removed and the Text Watcher was still set watching for it.

The **List Adapter** and **Object** were replaced, and I'm guessing the **Text Watcher** was looking the other way when it happened.

So the warning goes off and miraculously the **Text Watcher** finds the **HeaderView** and the **Object**.  But it loses focus and logs that warning.

Using

```
JOBSadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

fixed the issue.

**BUT** if you have an **Object** inside the **Adapter**, and the **Text Watcher** is attached to the **Object** inside the **Adapter**.  Then you may need to do a little more work.

Try removing the Listener and attach it again after doing whatever work you may be doing.

```
Object.removeTextChangedListener();
```

or

```
Object.addTextChangedListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

...I don't know how I ended up initializing my controllers under the build; but I did.

```
 `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 final prodName = TextEditingController();
 final prodDesc = TextEditingController();
 final prodPrice = TextEditingController();
 ...`
```

in the stead of

```
`final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 final prodName = TextEditingController();
 final prodDesc = TextEditingController();
 final prodPrice = TextEditingController();
 ...
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {`
```

it all went away(as expected) after I rightfully placed the controllers and the GlobalKey to my form, ofcourse!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had to modify or get text from EditText and it was focused.

So before modify or get from it, I closed keyboard and I fix it.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Maybe, your problem is different.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved my problem inserting a input type on xml like this:
android:inputType="none|text|textCapWords|textUri"

before that was android:inputType="text"
This solved my problem.

Comment: Did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Error in Logcat: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

Solution: **Hide Your Input Keyboard** and run the application.

Answer (score 0):

**Hide software keyboard before clearing EditText** - warnings will not be shown.

Also, It seems to be **device specific**. I've seen it only on Nexus 4 (Android 7.1). No warnings on emulators (8.0, 7.1) or Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by setting the visibility of the `EditText` to `GONE` and then immediately setting it to `VISIBLE` each time the user typed a character, as I was running validation on the input each time the text changed and in some cases the view needed to be hidden.

The solution is therefore to avoid setting the View or Layout's visibility to GONE between UI or state updates, as the `EditText` may lose focus

Answer (score 0):

iface the same problem and fix it by convert my stateless widget to statefull widget you can try it

Answer (score 0):

It has a really simple fix.
Whenever using Textformfield just put autofocus==true.
Worked for me!