# Android Log errors

Tags: android

I have tried this a few times, even with a brand new application package and I keep getting this error. I don't believe its something major but then again I don't know much about the error and why its occurring, so can someone please shed some light on this topic.

Occurs right after I lock the phone and then unlock it.

```
03-02 19:53:06.270: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29313): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 19:53:06.270: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29313): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 19:53:06.270: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29313): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: It is not an error, it's a warning.

Comment: Did you try to google this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android