# inactive InputConnection warning in all EditText box

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application, i am getting 3 "inactive InputConnection" warning (logCat below) every time I do anything with cursor on an EditText field.

This warnings popup even if I select another EditText (with cursor is one EditText), or just click on a button, or whatever I do with cursor in an EditText. This behavior is consistent in all the pages (activities).

Even if I click on any Menu button (to go another page) or back button with focus on an EditText field, the same set of warnings pop up.

In some Activity where I don't have any EditText, I don't have this problem.

This problem occurs when I try in real device (Samsung Note II), but does not replicate when I try in emulator.

Do anybody has an idea how to deal with this?

**LogCat:**

```
11-27 22:23:44.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25490): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-27 22:23:44.850: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25490): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-27 22:23:44.850: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25490): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android) is relevant...

Comment: unlike that case, I get the warning even if I don't have any action on EditText box

Comment: Agreed. I get it if I just popup a keyboard and even do nothing with it but back it down again, then back out of my app and I get the warning. If I don't pop up that keyboard I don't get this. And I'm not even doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code to manifest:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

Comment: This causes the view not to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you use `getIntent()` or `new Intent()`.

When i use `getIntent()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setClass(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

at first run all works, but at second run its produce a warning and application was shut down:

> V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.{package}
>
> V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default
>
> I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
>
> I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
>
> I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2c4c94c8 time:61939164
>
> I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.{package} time:61942367
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>
> D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x5589e3a5f0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x5589d7c0e0

When i use `new Intent()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

app is works normally.