# Getting warning on clicking on any text box

Tags: java, android

I m getting below warning when i click on any text box.Please help

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Below is the `Mainactivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

        private EditText editTextName;
        private EditText editTextUsername;
        private EditText editTextPassword;
        private EditText editTextEmail;

        private Button buttonRegister;

        private static final String REGISTER_URL = "********************";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
            editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
            editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

            buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

            buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == buttonRegister){
                registerUser();
            }
        }

        private void registerUser() {
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

            register(name,username,password,email);
        }

        private void register(String name, String username, String password, String email) {
            String urlSuffix = "?name="+name+"&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&email="+email;
            class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

                ProgressDialog loading;


                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String s = params[0];
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                        String result;

                        result = bufferedReader.readLine();

                        return result;
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

            RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
            ru.execute(urlSuffix);
        }
    }
```

what is this warning ? how can i avoid it?

Comment: you can add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" from  activity in manifest

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android

Comment: @Vadivel i already added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" But still not working