# Getting Warning on InputConnectionWrapper

Tags: android

I am having these warning every time I try to enter text on my editText.

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>       beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: commitText on inactive InputConnection
>       endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection**

This always occurs when I try to close my App, and open it again. 
I need to click on my imagebutton first before I can enter again on my editText.

Tried Researching but cant find solution for this.

Comment: I think the warning is not much clear. Please can you update this post according to the correct format.

Comment: Hi, that's the only warning message I get every time I click on my keyboard

Comment: using emulator or actual device?, is it android studio or some other tool, what is the requirement etc. If you can provide more info it would be grate. thanks.

Comment: I am running my android app on my actual device.
And I am using Android studio for creating the app.

Comment: upon further investigating, I have found that when  I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus is started on my Logcat, that's when I can enter again some text on my editText.


It takes time before that Info appear on my logcat.

Comment: did you solve this..

Comment: Nope, I stilll don't get the reason on why I am unable to type text on my editText.

Comment: I think its better to publish your code here. then you can get a better solution.

Comment: But the problem is, I don't know where that error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

this is not 100% sure answer. I can't comment it because then it will not clear.

According to this article they suggest you to Hide Your Input Keyboard and run the application.

following code will give an idea, how you should do it.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

as a reference you can use this - : [getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection warning on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android)

try this. If this not worked please comment down below. We will try to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I believe this didn't solved my problem.
I already tried implementing this code, and also tried to set focus and remove focus on my imagebutton, but still not working.