# beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection, after lost focus on editText, trigger AGAIN editText onchange

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

My question almost same like

[getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection warning on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)

When i editText, then i trigger something/like func A. Then i press **back** to lost focus on editText, then it trigger editText onchange multiple times(func A called multiple times).

when on editText onchange once (func A result) :

```
HIT KEY
```

When i lost focus ( It' will trigger as much as editText that shown and the result is func A called multiple times ) :

```
HIT KEY
HIT KEY
HIT KEY
HIT KEY
HIT KEY
HIT KEY
```

And my question is, why between them there is warning message :

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

How i can stop this warning, or someone could help me understand about this message. Why after this message pop up, trigger onchange editText again multiple times.

[image]

Some note :

- using Android Studio 3.5
- I'm using listView in CustomeAdapter :

  ```
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final ViewHolder holder;
      final String TAG = "get view ";

      if (convertView == null) {
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_item, null, true);

          holder.editTextCrt = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editidCrt);
          holder.editTextLsn = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editidLsn);
          holder.editTextPcs = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editidPcs);
          holder.editTextSeq = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editidSeq);
          holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewid);

          convertView.setTag(holder);
      }else {
          // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
          holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
      }

      holder.editTextCrt.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValueCrt());
      holder.editTextLsn.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValueLsn());
      holder.editTextPcs.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValuePcs());
      holder.editTextSeq.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValueSeq());
      holder.textView.setText(editModelArrayList.get(position).getTextViewValue());

      holder.editTextCrt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          boolean mToggle = false;
          boolean mToggle2 = false;

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
              if (mToggle) {
                  if (mToggle2) {
                      if(s.length() != 0){
                          Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: HIT KEY" );
                          editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValueCrt(holder.editTextCrt.getText().toString());
                      }
                  }
                  mToggle2 = !mToggle2;
              }
              mToggle = !mToggle;
          }
      }
  }
  ```