# Textfield show weird log in console (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield, flutter-test

When i click on Textfield in My app The console show this

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10655): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10655): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10655): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10655): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10655): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

this is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUJCf.png) of my application that i'am working on it

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and there's a lot of methods to try fix it but nothing official.

Github issue:

- [TextFields generate many warning/error messages in debug mode](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471)

You can try:

- [Method 1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471#issuecomment-864352277)
- [Method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732554)
- [Method 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22223658)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using a methods like

```
onChanged()
onFieldSubmitted()
onEditCompleted()
```