# IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

Please help. I am getting the below warnings when typing text values in Jetpack Compose TextField. The UI freezes and text is not updated after entering one letter.The logcat also gets flooded with repeated messages over and over(if I log inside `onValueChanged`). This seems to happen in Android devices of version 9.0 and below. When entering numeric values the keyboard is responsive but when entering text values the UI freezes and the keyboard become unresponsive.

```
   IInputConnectionWrapper    W beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
   IInputConnectionWrapper    W  setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
   IInputConnectionWrapper    W  endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122625/getextractedtext-on-inactive-inputconnection-warning-on-android) can help you, I know it's not jetpack related but it analize the warning.